# Excel VBA to copy flagged text from one word file to another word file

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Word File containing flagged blocks of text viz:

```
Text 1
Text 1 Line 1
Text 1 Line 2
Text 1 End

Text 2
Text 2 Line 1 
Text 2 Line 2
Text 2 Line 3
     .
     .
Text 2 Line N
Text 2 End

etc.
```

I need my Excel Macro to find blocks of text between the specified flags "Text X" and "Test X End" then take a copy of the text (not including the flags) and paste it into a second Word Document at a specified location.

I've tried tweaking many of the solutions posted on stack exchange but have been unable to get these to compile and/or run as most seem to assume that I am writing my macro from within Word rather than Excel.

My reason for working within Excel is that I am adding functionality to an existing suite of Excel macros accessed via an Excel Interface.

Current State of the code is:

```
Sub Word_In_Word_Out()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Path = ThisWorkbook.Path
Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wrdApp.Visible = True
Set inDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(Path & "\" & "Word Input" & ".docx")
inDoc.Activate

Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim strTheText As String

Set rng1 = ActiveDocument.Range
If rng1.Find.Execute(FindText:="Text 2") Then
    Set rng2 = ActiveDocument.Range(rng1.End, ActiveDocument.Range.End)
    If rng2.Find.Execute(FindText:="Text 2 End") Then
        strTheText = ActiveDocument.Range(rng1.End, rng2.Start).Text
        MsgBox strTheText
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

This currently stops compilation at the line:

{If rng1.Find.Execute(FindText:="Text 2") Then}

with ".Find" highlighted and an "Argument not Optional" error message

Comment: Add some code so we can see how far you've gotten. Also, please explain why you are running this in Excel.

Comment: Code added as per your request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Excel and Word have a `Range` object. Because you are in Excel VBA but are trying to reference the Word `Range` object you need to qualify the variable declaration so that Excel knows you are using a Word `Range` object.

```
Dim rng1 As Word.Range
Dim rng2 As Word.Range
```

You also do not need to use the `ActiveDocument` because you have already created a reference to the document using `inDoc`. So in your code replace `ActiveDocument` by `inDoc`.

Having made these changes, your code sample worked for me using a small test document.